# Validation of text fields and email fields using regular expression

Tags: regex, silverlight-3.0

I want to validate my text fields and the text fields should not allow

> > << < > ( ) { } [ ] ? & * ~ ` ! # $ % ^ = + | \ : ' " , ; 
> >     any of the above special characters and can contain - _ @ / . these special characters.
> >     How can i do it? The same thing applies to my email field also.
> >     Can any one help me out with this?

Thanks in advance
Ravikiran

Answer (score 0):

^(?("")("".+?""@)|((0-9a-zA-Z*)(?<=[0-9a-zA-Z])@))(?([)([(\d{1,3}.){3}\d{1,3}])|(([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z].)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}))$

this is a good one (taken off Microsoft's site)

[MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I've enclosed all the special characters (plus escaped all of them) you don't want in your fields in this expression,

```
\[\<\>\(\)\{\}\[\]\?\&\*\~\`\!\#\$\%\^\=\+\|\\\:\'\"\,\;]\
```

I think you can do validation like this, try to match this expression on each of your fields, if it finds a match, that field is invalid, else it's valid as it doesn't contain any of the special characters.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to use javascript for this with following code.

Code:

```
function isSpclChar(){
var iChars = "!#$%^&*()+=[]\\\';,{}|\":<>?";
for (var i = 0; i < document.qfrm.q.value.length; i++) {
if (iChars.indexOf(document.qfrm.q.value.charAt(i)) != -1) {
alert ("The box has special characters. \nThese are not allowed.\n");
return false;
        }
    }
}
```